# How to get the IP address of Heroku so that my Heroku hosted backend server can connect to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, express, heroku, networking

I'm trying to host my backend on Heroku, but after I tried deploying I was getting an "application error" . I checked the "heroku logs" and I think the problem is my MongoDB database only accepts connection to my specific IP address.

```
2023-02-07T09:34:05.807213+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
```

How do I get the IP address of Heroku so that I can add it to this whitelist?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZvRT.png

---

This is the entire Heroku log just in case maybe I'm wrong about the reason it's crashing?

https://pastebin.com/btc79fQq

EDIT:

Also is there a way to connect to the mongo atlas database with username + password instead of IP address maybe?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's very dynamic so you need an addon like [Fixie socks](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fixie-socks) which sets a static IP of your Heroku app for this exact purpose.